# I want to convert file:///storage/sdcard0/blue.jpg to content://media/external/images/media/3163 in android

Tags: android

I want to upload image, audio and video files from my app. If I select image using Gallery (`content://media/external/images/media/3163`) it works fine, but if I select using File Manager (`file:///storage/sdcard0/blue.jpg`) it is not working.

```
uri=intent.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };
if (uri != null) {
     Cursor cursor = RootActivity.rootContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(uri),filePathColumn, null, null, null);
}
```

The cursor returns null if `uri = file:///storage/sdcard0/blue.jpg`, can any one help me?

Comment: is it directly located on sdcard or inside a folder?

Comment: Is this a Samsung device ? If so, look here:  http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=162934&messageNumber=1381&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=TITLE&searchText=sdcard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
```

and add two methods in your activity

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String s1 = data.getDataString();
            //String s1 = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            Log.e("GetPath",s1);
            Log.e("OK",""+selectedImageUri);

            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if(selectedImagePath==null && s1 != null)
            {
                selectedImagePath = s1.replaceAll("file://","");
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("path", selectedImagePath);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
                  }
               }


//Return the path of the file.
   public String getPath(Uri uri) {

    try{
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Log.e("OK 1",""+projection);
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    Log.e("OK 2",""+cursor);
    if(cursor==null)
    {
        return null;

    }
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    Log.e("OK 3",""+column_index);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.e("OK 4",""+cursor.getString(column_index));
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Image is too big in resolution please try again", 5).show();
        return null;
    }

}
```

and add this int as class member

```
  private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```